# Distinguishing Between Brute force and Crawlers in error reporting

Tags: web-application, web-browser, brute-force, ip

I have been receiving a great many emails recently reporting issues within my website that, when gone back and looked up, have been reported as being Brute force attacks. Upon further inspection of their location. I have noticed a great deal of them are coming from the same IP address, and seem to be linked 
to Google, or Yahoo for example this site:

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/104.199.203.53

reports the following IP: 104.199.203.53, Which originates from google cloud, as brute force.

Is there a good way to distinguish between apparent brute force attacks, and Crawlers checking the site?

Update: all emails are being generated from production site. The error reporting is issuing a null reference exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute forcing usually applies to sending user/password combinations to your login endpoint. So what you see in a brute force attack is thousands of HTTP POST requests to the URL behind which your login logic resides.

Crawling has a completely different profile. A crawler will hit your website at any entry point, most likely the site's homepage, and start following links from there. Benign crawlers never send POST requests; they simply GET each page, look at the links on that page and later on GET the linked pages. Well-written crawlers will also honor robots.txt, so if you list your login endpoint in robots.txt, crawlers shouldn't request it. Plus well-written crawlers follow rate limits you suggest.

The source IP is completely irelevant in determining whether you're dealing with a crawler or a brute force attack. Both crawlers and brute force attacks may originate from a single IP, or be distributed over several or even hundreds of different IPs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I didn't want to start forcing a block if it wasn't necessary, especially if it was going to affect potential traffic.